# Filter an Array of Objects from an Array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I built a custom component that filters an array of objects. The filter uses buttons, sets from active to non-active and allows more than one option on/off at the same time.

StackBlitz of my attempt - https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-ut6fxu

In my demo you will see 3 buttons/options of north, south and east. By clicking on one you make it active and the result should include or exclude a matching "location" either north, south and east.

I have created my methods and structure to do the filtering, I'm struggling with the final piece of logic.

So far I have created a method to create an array of filtered locations depending on what the user clicks from the 3 buttons.

Next this passes to my "filter array" that gets the logic that should compare this filtered array against the original to bring back the array of results that are still remaining.

Its not quite working and not sure why - I originally got this piece of functionality working by using a pipe, but fore reasons do not want to go in that direction.

```
//the action
  toggle(location) {
    let indexLocation = this.filteredLocations.indexOf(location);

    if (indexLocation >= 0) {
      this.filteredLocations = this.filteredLocations.filter(
        i => i !== location
      );
    } else {
      this.filteredLocations.push({ location });
    }
    this.filterTimeLine();
  }

// the filter
  filterTimeLine() {
    this.filteredTimeline = this.timeLine.filter(x =>
      this.contactMethodFilter(x)
    );
  }

//the logic
  private contactMethodFilter(entry) {
    const myArrayFiltered = this.timeLine.filter(el => {
      return this.filteredLocations.some(f => {
        return f.location === el.location;
      });
    });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-ut6fxu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my expression but u have a disaster in your code. jajaja!. maybe u lost that what u need but the logic in your functions in so wrong. comparing string with objects. filter a array that filter the same array inside... soo u need make a few changes.

One:

```
 this.filteredLocations.push({location});
```

Your are pushing object. u need push only the string.

```
 this.filteredLocations.push(location);
```

Two:

```
  filterTimeLine() {
    this.filteredTimeline = this.timeLine.filter(x =>
      this.contactMethodFilter(x)
    );
  }
```

in this function you filter the `timeLine` array. and inside of  `contactMethodFilter` you call filter method to timeLine again....

See a functional solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-rg7k3j

Comment: Been racking my brains - on number one did not mean to leave this in there and same for number 2. the logic and returning the new array was what was not working for me. Thanks pal

Answer (score 0):

```
private contactMethodFilter(entry) {
    const myArrayFiltered = this.timeLine.filter(el => {
      return this.filteredLocations.some(f => {
        return f.location === el.location;
      });
    });
  }
```

This function is not returning any value and is passed to the `.filter`

Consider returning a boolean based on your logic. Currently the filter gets undefined(falsy) and everything would be filtered out